# Conditional shiny UI when multiple conditions need to be handled

Tags: javascript, r, user-interface, conditional-statements, shiny

### Actual question

How do I design(*) a shiny app where certain UI elements depend on *multiple* conditions that need to be systematically handled?

(*) in a maintainable way that won't drive you mad ;-)

---

### Details

I've read [Build a dynamic UI that reacts to user input](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/dynamic-ui.html) and like `conditionalPanel()`, but I have the feeling it's too "one-dimensional" for the [timetracking app](https://rappster.shinyapps.io/timetrackr) I would like to build ([source code on GitHub](https://github.com/rappster/timetrackr/tree/stackoverflow_20151215)).

**What I want to be able to do:**

1. Have one (or more) UI element(s) that can trigger conditional UI parts:

   *State 1*

   [image: State 1]
2. Those conditional UI parts usually have some input fields and at least two action buttons: `Create` and `Cancel`:

   *State 2*

   [image: State 2]
3. If `Create` is clicked, the input should be appropriately processed (e.g. writing stuff to a DB) and then the conditional UI part should "disappear" again as its condition "expired":

   *State 3*

   [image: State 3]

   *State 4*

   [image: State 4]
4. If `Cancel` is clicked, the UI part should "disappear" again as its condition "expired":

   *State 4*

   [image: State 4]
5. A subsequent click on `Trigger` should "start the cycle" again

**Problem with multiple dependencies and dynamic dependency states:**

AFAIU, if I simply put the dependencies (i.e. `input$action_trigger`, `input$action_create` and `input$action_cancel` below) into the reactive context that builds the conditional UI, then I face multiple rounds of invalidation until all dependencies have reached a stable state (see `output$ui_conditional <- renderUI({})` below).

From a UX-perspective, this feels like having to click on elements multiple times until you get what you want (check out an example of this "multiple-clicks-necessary" behavior in my [timetracking app](https://rappster.shinyapps.io/timetrackr)).

That's why I came up with the idea of introducing sort of a "dependency state clearance" layer (see `ui_decision <- reactive({})` below)

### Current solution

My current solution feels very wrong, very fragile and very high maintenance. You can also find it at [GitHub](https://github.com/rappster/stackoverflow/blob/master/shiny/conditional/2015-12-15/app.R)

**Globals:**

```
library(shiny)

GLOBALS <- list()
GLOBALS$debug$enabled <- TRUE

# Auxiliary functions -----------------------------------------------------

createDynamicUi_conditional <- function(
  input,
  output,
  ui_decision,
  debug = GLOBALS$debug$enabled
) {
  if (debug) {
    message("Dynamic UI: conditional ----------")
    print(Sys.time())
  }

  ## Form components //
  container <- list()

  field <- "title"
  name <- "Title"
  value <- ""
  container[[field]] <- textInput(field, name, value)

  field <- "description"
  name <- "Description"
  value <- ""
  container[[field]] <- textInput(field, name, value)

  ## Bundle in box //
  value <- if (ui_decision == "hide") {
    div()
  } else if (ui_decision == "show" || ui_decision == "create") {
    container$buttons <- div(style="display:inline-block",
      actionButton("action_create", "Create"),
      actionButton("action_cancel", "Cancel")
    )
    do.call(div, args = list(container, title = "conditional dynamic UI"))
  } else {
    "Not implemented yet"
  }
  # print(value)
  value
}
```

**UI part:**

```
# UI ----------------------------------------------------------------------

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("action_trigger", "Trigger 1"),
  h3("Database state"),
  textOutput("result"),
  p(),
  uiOutput("ui_conditional")
)
```

**Server part:**

```
# Server ------------------------------------------------------------------

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  #####################
  ## REACTIVE VALUES ##
  #####################

  db <- reactiveValues(
    title = "",
    description = ""
  )

  ui_control <- reactiveValues(
    action_trigger = 0,
    action_trigger__last = 0,
    action_create = 0,
    action_create__last = 0,
    action_cancel = 0,
    action_cancel__last = 0
  )

  #################
  ## UI DECISION ##
  #################

  ui_decision <- reactive({
    ## Dependencies //
    ## Trigger button:
    value <- input$action_trigger
    if (ui_control$action_trigger != value) ui_control$action_trigger <- value

    ## Create button:
    ## Dynamically created within `createDynamicUi_conditional`
    value <- input$action_create
    if (is.null(value)) {
      value <- 0
    }
    if (ui_control$action_create != value) {
      ui_control$action_create <- value
    }

    ## Cancel button:
    ## Dynamically created within `createDynamicUi_conditional`
    value <- input$action_cancel
    if (is.null(value)) {
      value <- 0
    }
    if (ui_control$action_cancel != value) {
      ui_control$action_cancel <- value
    }

    if (GLOBALS$debug$enabled) {
      message("Dependency clearance -----")
      message("action_trigger:")
      print(ui_control$action_trigger)
      print(ui_control$action_trigger__last)
      message("action_create:")
      print(ui_control$action_create)
      print(ui_control$action_create__last)
      message("action_cancel:")
      print(ui_control$action_cancel)
      print(ui_control$action_cancel__last)
    }
    ui_decision <- if (
      c (ui_control$action_trigger == 0 && ui_control$action_trigger == 0) ||
        c(
          ui_control$action_trigger > 0 &&
            ui_control$action_trigger <= ui_control$action_trigger__last &&

            ui_control$action_cancel > 0 &&
            ui_control$action_cancel > ui_control$action_cancel__last
        ) ||
        c(
          ui_control$action_create == 0 &&
            ui_control$action_create__last > 0
        )
    ) {
      "hide"
    } else if (
      ui_control$action_trigger >= ui_control$action_trigger__last &&
        ui_control$action_create == ui_control$action_create__last
    ) {
      ## Synchronize //
      ui_control$action_cancel__last <- ui_control$action_cancel
      "show"
    } else if (
      ui_control$action_create > ui_control$action_create__last
    ) {
      "create"
    } else {
      "Not implemented yet"
    }
    if (GLOBALS$debug$enabled) {
      print(ui_decision)
    }
    ## Synchronize //
    ui_control$action_trigger__last <- ui_control$action_trigger
    ui_control$action_create__last <- ui_control$action_create

    ui_decision
  })

  output$ui_conditional <- renderUI({
    createDynamicUi_conditional(input, output, ui_decision = ui_decision())
  })

  #################
  ## WRITE TO DB ##
  #################

  writeToDb <- reactive({
    ui_decision <- ui_decision()
    if (ui_decision == "create") {
      db$title <- input$title
      db$description <- input$description
    }
  })

  ###################
  ## RENDER RESULT ##
  ###################

  output$result <- renderText({
    writeToDb()
    c(
      paste0("Title: ", db$title),
      paste0("Description: ", db$description)
    )
  })
}
```

**Running the app:**

```
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

### Big picture

This is the app that I'm actually having in mind: [`timetrackr`](https://rappster.shinyapps.io/timetrackr)

[Source code on GitHub](https://github.com/rappster/timetrackr/tree/stackoverflow_20151215).

It has been build without introducing a clearance layer as drafted above. While it does provide the desired functionality, very often, you need to click UI elements more than once until a stable dependency state is reached which is really irritating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll start with the solution:

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("action_trigger", "Trigger 1"),
  h3("Database state"),
  textOutput("result"),
  p(),
  uiOutput("ui_conditional")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  ui_control <- reactiveValues(show = FALSE)

  output$ui_conditional <- renderUI({
    if (!ui_control$show) return()

    tagList(
      textInput("title", "Title"),
      textInput("description", "Description"),
      div(style="display:inline-block",
        actionButton("action_create", "Create"),
        actionButton("action_cancel", "Cancel")
      )
    )
  })

  observeEvent(input$action_trigger, {
    ui_control$show <- TRUE
  })
  observeEvent(input$action_create, {
    writeToDb()
    ui_control$show <- FALSE
  })
  observeEvent(input$action_cancel, {
    ui_control$show <- FALSE
  })

  writeToDb <- function() {
    # ...
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I hope that this is sufficiently simple as to be self-explanatory. Let me know if it is not.

There are several principles that you can follow to make your Shiny reactive code much more robust and maintainable--and usually simpler, too.

1. Each action button should have its own `observeEvent`, and you generally shouldn't need to use the action button value anywhere but as the first argument to `observeEvent`. It's rarely advisable to use an action button any other way, even though it can be tempting; especially if you're comparing the action button's value to its previous value, that's a pretty sure sign that you're on the wrong track.
2. Reactive expressions should never have side effects--e.g. writing to disk, or assigning to non-local variables (and reactive value objects like ui_control count as non-local variables when you set them from inside a reactive expression). These type of actions should instead be done in an `observe()` or `observeEvent()`. I will elaborate much more on this in early 2016.
3. Like regular functions, reactive expressions and observers should ideally have a single responsibility--one calculation or coherent set of calculations (in the case of reactive expressions), or one action or coherent set of actions (in the case of observers). If you're having trouble thinking of an informative and specific name for a function, that can be a sign that the function is doing too much; the same is true for reactive expressions (in this case, `ui_decision` is pretty vague).
4. In response to your general concern about instability while dynamically built UI/inputs come online, when you need to use such inputs, you can guard their invocations with `validate(need(input$foo, FALSE))`. You can put this in e.g. the beginning of a reactive expression, and it will silently abort execution of itself and any callers if `input$foo` is not yet available (i.e. it's `NULL`, `FALSE`, `""`, or a number of other falsy values). This is a hugely helpful feature of Shiny that we have done a notably poor job of promoting. I also think we made the API too general and not easy enough to use, which I hope to rectify soon. In the meantime, see http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/validation.html and/or https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7sQ6AEDFjZ4.

Comment: Awesome, thank you so much! Exactly I was hoping for with respect to simplicity and maintainability. And also great to learn about `validate()` and `need()`, I had no clue they existed!

Comment: I added an alternate solution. I'd be interested to know if you (Joe) have any insights on why this solution should be used vs my shinyjs approach, or if you find both equally good

Answer (score 2):

The solution given by Joe is great (obviously, as he wrote Shiny...) and has lots of useful detailed information, so I don't want to take away from that, but I would like to offer another approach to solve the conditional UI problem.

You could use the `shinyjs` package to show or hide UI elements on demand.  I find this to be a much simpler and cleaner solution when you do require a non-trivial condition for showing/hiding UI.  Here's the code, modified slightly from Joe's answer:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(),
  actionButton("action_trigger", "Trigger 1"),
  h3("Database state"),
  textOutput("result"),
  p(),
  div(
    id = "ui_control",
    textInput("title", "Title"),
    textInput("description", "Description"),
    div(style="display:inline-block",
        actionButton("action_create", "Create"),
        actionButton("action_cancel", "Cancel")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$action_trigger, {
    show("ui_control")
  })
  observeEvent(input$action_create, {
    writeToDb()
    hide("ui_control")
  })
  observeEvent(input$action_cancel, {
    hide("ui_control")
  })

  writeToDb <- function() {
    # ...
  }
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

As you can see, the only difference here is that I moved the UI back into the ui portion instead of being created with a `renderUI`, added a div with an id to the UI section that you want to show/hide, and used `shinyjs::show` or `shinyjs::hide` instead of a reactive value.

I personally find this a bit easier because it keeps your UI in your UI rather than needing to move it into the server, and it also is more intuitive to me to just call a show/hide function rather than use a reactive value that will trigger a rewrite of the HTML.

However, since this isn't exactly the way Shiny is meant to be used (this solution bypasses reactivity), I'd be interested to know if Joe has any comments on using this approach vs the more native Shiny approach that he wrote.

Comment: Interesting! Thanks for demonstrating this, I didn't know `shinyjs` before. Keeping the UI in the UI part does seem intriguing, yet  I also really came to love shiny's reactive design. In any case: good to know there exists multiple options for realizing conditional UI!

Comment: That'd be totally fine as well. I think the main thing is the proper usage of `observeEvent` to manage the viewing/hiding which your solution does equally well as mine.

Comment: Yes, I'm quite a big fan of `observeEvent`. Thanks